# After Cropping a picture: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{

Tags: android

In my app the user is able to select a photo from gallery, crop it and set is as their avatar. 
When they sign up, Im sending this photo to the server.

In order to send it, I have to obtain it first, but Im getting an error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo
{who=null, request=2, result=-1,     data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }}
 to activity {net.asdasd.asdasd/net.asdasd.activities.Signup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my code:

```
bSelectPhotoFromFileSignupPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();

                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                        cropImage();

                        break;

                case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                        cropImage();

                        break;                    

                case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:    

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    setAvatarPath(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
                    // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
                    userAvatarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(userAvatarPath);
                    //Set the button image to be the newly created image instead of the default
                    iUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(userAvatarBitmap);

                    //delete the temporary file
                    File temporaryAvatarFile = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
                    if (temporaryAvatarFile.exists()) temporaryAvatarFile.delete();

                    break;

        }
    }


public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}

public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> options;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int imageView;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options, int imageView) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_layout_signup, options);

        this.options = options;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout_signup, null);

        CropOption item = options.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageView)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here is the whole log:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {net.asd.asd/net.asd.activities.Signup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:743)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
   at net.asd.activities.Signup.onActivityResult(Signup.java:357)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
    ... 11 more
```

Line 357 is the following:

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for nulls as the getData method can return null:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();  

if(selectedImage != null){
...
}
```

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933737/570612